# App not doing any type payment with paypal android sdk.

Tags: android, paypal, payment, paypal-rest-sdk

*
hi ,
i have created  an android app in which we have used  Android Paypal gateway for payment .

its working well on test account ,but when i am using it with  live client-id
its giving following error:

1.when using Pay with Paypal button :

"There was a problem setting this payment .account needs a valid funding source ,such as a bank or payment card . Please visit..."

2. when using pay with credit card:

"The Merchant does not accept payments of this type"

If anyone who belongs to india and implement's paypal android  sdk on their app..please give the step to go live .
*

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about that but many APIs provide debug key hash and a release one. If it works as testing purpose, maybe you have to find the release key...

Is there a bank account attached to your PayPal one ? Or do you have any restriction on your PayPal account ?

Comment: yes , bank account is attached to my paypal account.and there is no restriction.

Comment: Hi Ashish, did you found any solution to your problem.